# how to run select query for impala struct column

Tags: sql, database, impala, cloudera-cdh

Given table `address` as,

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| country | struct< name:string, city:array> |

I need a select query which would produce result set in the below structure? Query would be run by a java program.

| id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example_struct_object |
| 2 | example_struct_object |

Having [this](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_complex_types.html) in mind for impala - with regards to complex types.

> The result set of an Impala query always contains all scalar types;
> the elements and fields within any complex type queries must be
> "unpacked" using join queries.

ie. `select * from details;` would only return results without the struct column complex type).

Thanks.